# how to sum elements among each other like arr[i] + arr[i+1] in python

Tags: python, arrays, sum, element

I would like to create a function that sums first two elements and so on. 
Like:

```
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    result = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]
```

I did something like that but got no results

```
def Consec_Sum(arr):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        result = result.append(arr[i]+arr[i+1])
    return result
```

Comment: which programming language? You mean a prefix sum operation? I would like to know if there is a statistically significant correlation between questions that are not tagged with a programming language and `javascript` :D

Comment: sorry, I edited the question. I hope it is clarified

Comment: `append` doesn't return the list. If you remove `result = ` your code should work.

Comment: i removed the result= part but still have a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def Consec_Sum(arr):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        result.append(arr[i]+arr[i+1])
    print(result)

Consec_Sum(arr)
```

Result

```
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]
```

I didn't analize the code. Just removed `result =`.

More similar to your code:

```
 arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

 def Consec_Sum(arr):
     result = []
     for i in range(len(arr)-1):
         result.append(arr[i]+arr[i+1])
     return result

 print(Consec_Sum(arr))
```